# Message from a shy user

Tags: discussion, support

How can I make sure I'm not distracting researchers from their work, with a bunch of questions.

I feel I could ask a lot, primarily because I have studied very little.

I don't think I could ask a lot, if I had studied a lot.

I don't really think my questions will not permit the descriptive aspects of the science to progress.

I, also, think, my questions, might lead to progress.

Am I invited to ask, on this site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

That's actually a great question. I think the is a balance, and whether to post or not is something you will have to decide about. Here are some considerations before posting...

You should not ask questions that are already answered on this (or other) stack exchange site. This necessarily requires you do some sort of research. I think (at least) you should try to google the question phrased in a bunch of different ways. It's fairly possible that the answer does exist online, but you just don't know what to search for, but that is fine, but it should be clear that you (or the poster) made an effort to find the answer your/themselves.

There is also the factor of "how much useful is this going to be for others". Those that are of general interest are always very welcomed questions. You can see that some of the old questions are really heavily used resource, while some other are so specific are seen only few times. So, more general question you will have, the better. Sometimes it is good to think if you can phrase your question in a more general way.

Finally, consider how frequently you post yourself and how keen are people to help you out (I think there is a bit of common sense). If it feels all alright, it probably is. SE folks are not the subtlest in explaining to people what's sub-optimal about their questions.

So to sum up, you can ask as many relevant questions as you want, even if they are basic, if you don't annoy the heck out of the community (and you will be able to tell). Stuff to make people like your questions:

- Be concrete, give details, but cohesive and preferentially reproducible (with toy data and small snippets of code).
- Show initiative and do your own research, that will both help others to understand the true source of your problem, but also make you more relatable.
- Disclaim everything that should be disclaimed - is it homework? Are you a developer of the method you are discussing? etc.
- Be polite and kind, but don't write "Thanks" or apologize for basic questions, that is all fine. Gratitude should be expressed through upvotes or [accepting](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the right answer (that makes the answer more useful for the next person facing the same problem).

So don't worry THAT much, just ask :-)